# PHP String Search and Replace wildcard for numbers written in text

Tags: php, regex, search, replace

I search around and could not find a simple solution for this specific case. I am not a PHP professional and am still learning.

I am performing a String Search and Replace for numbers written in text to convert them back to numbers. A small example is shown below:

```
$n_0='twenty one'; $n_1='twenty two'; $n_2='twenty three'; $n_3='twenty four'; $n_4='twenty five'; $n_5='twenty six'; $n_6='twenty seven'; $n_7='twenty eight'; $n_8='twenty nine'; $n_9='thirty one';

$r_0='21'; $r_1='22'; $r_2='23'; $r_3='24'; $r_4='25'; $r_5='26'; $r_6='27'; $r_7='28'; $r_8='29'; $r_9='31';

$search = array($n_0, $n_1, $n_2, $n_3, $n_4, $n_5, $n_6, $n_7, $n_8, $n_9, $n_10, $n_11, $n_12, $n_13, $n_14, $n_15, $n_16, $n_17, $n_18, $n_19, $n_20, $n_21, $n_22);

$replace = array($r_0, $r_1, $r_2, $r_3, $r_4, $r_5, $r_6, $r_7, $r_8, $r_9, $r_10, $r_11, $r_12, $r_13, $r_14, $r_15, $r_16, $r_17, $r_18, $r_19, $r_20, $r_21, $r_22);

$string = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Is there a way to define a "single" PHP variable such that all the given conditions will be found?

**For Example:**

```
Search for: $n_0='twenty???one';
Replace with: $r_0 = '21';
```

where **???** is some wildcard code between the "twenty" and the "one" that will make it work for all of the following Search for cases.

**Search for:**

```
$n_0='twenty one';
$n_0='twenty, one';
$n_0='twenty,one';
$n_0='twenty-one';
$n_0='twenty:one';
$n_0='twenty_one';
$n_0='twenty*one';
$n_0='twenty(one';
$n_0='twenty)one';
$n_0='twentyone';
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `preg_replace` rather than `str_ireplace`, and use regular expressions with wildcards.

Comment: @Barmar How would it be done? and example would help.

Comment: It seems like a pretty trivial regular expression, but I posted an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$n_0 = '/twenty[-\s,:_()*]*one/';
...
preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$pattern = array('/twenty[^a-zA-Z]*?one/','/twenty[^a-zA-Z]*?two/');
$replace = array('21','22');
$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, "I love twentyone but really love twenty238two");

echo $result;
```

Comment: Try your example with the string `I love twenty but not two`.

Comment: @Tom Pace Is there a wildcard to replace the ??? in $n_0='twenty???one. I have over 100 text number combinations to replace. I would only need to replace one character between the words.

Comment: I would suggest .*?  which lazily catches anything between twenty and one.  But like Barmar said, it will replace something like "I love twenty but not two" with "I love 22".

Comment: @Sammy I fixed the regex from .*?  to [^a-zA-Z]*?. It covers Barmar's point.

Comment: @Sammy this regex is a catch-all regex, it will catch other things not covered by your examples.  Such as "twenty#one" and "twenty!one"... I don't know if that's important to you.

Comment: @Tom Pace - thanks for the regex and all your help. I can definetely use it. take care

Comment: @Sammy glad I can help. Btw, did Barmar's answer solve the case of "twenty???one"?

Comment: @Tom Pace Barmar's answer worked great initially for both the format and function. I ended up using your regex answer to cover almost all situations, but I had to modify it to take into account line breaks and numerical values too. The new regex is now:
    $n_0 = '/twenty((<br>)|[^a-z0-9]*?)one/i';
which I replaced in Barmar's answer. Again thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression will do:

```
preg_replace('/twenty(?:[-:_\*\(\)]|,? ?)one/', '21', $n_0);
```

What it does is:

- Search for a string containint "twenty"
- followed by any of - : _ * ( or ) OR followed by an optional comma followed by an optional space
- followed by "one"